# Show parent container's background over child img

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/33g7e/2/

This is example HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/XecoFpD.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/mQ0MeUc.png') no-repeat left top transparent;
    display: block;
}
ul.menu {
    padding: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
ul.menu li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

There's a hidden background (a black bar) under img element, you can see it if you remove img. So I need to show it over the image without changing the structure of html.

Comment: It's <ul><li> to be exact. I updated the code.

Comment: I don't know why yet, but the `background` attribute given to `.container` in the CSS code clearly isn't working.

Comment: Yes black bar was gone after I added <ul>, adjusted the CSS again, check now.

Comment: It's still not working for me @OptimusPrime

Comment: @OptimusPrime made a DEMO. check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the CSS code.** Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/berekete/1/edit)**.

```
ul.container li img {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
}

.container{
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/mQ0MeUc.png') no-repeat left top transparent;
}
```

**HTML Code is**

```
<ul class="container">
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/XecoFpD.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I prefer `jsbin` over `jsfiddle`. you can see result instantly on `jsbin`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

[**Demo: show on hover**](http://jsfiddle.net/33g7e/4/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/33g7e/9/)

```
<div class="container">
    <ul><li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/XecoFpD.jpg" /></li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: In this demo it only works when you hover mouse over it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/33g7e/6/`">code

Black image is exactly over the another image.